# Можно ли реализовать lazy load для таблицы без jQuery?

Tags: javascript

Столкнулась с задачей реализовать lazy load для таблицы без помощи jQuery. Гугл не помог, примеров более-менее адекватных и подходящий по тематике не нашла. Может кто-то еще сталкивался с такой задачей? Буду рада помощи.

Здесь получаю список статей с сервера и распарсиваю json-ответ в табличку:

```
ArticleController.prototype.getAllArticles = function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', '/api/posts', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa("admin" + ":" + "admin"));
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
            var items = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            var output = '';
            for (var key in items) {
                output += '<tr>';
                output += '<td>' + items[key].id + '</td>';
                output += '<td>' + items[key].title + '</td>';
                output += '<td>' + items[key].content + '</td>';
                output += '<td>' + items[key].author + '</td>';
                output += '<td>' + items[key].creation_date + '</td>';
                output += '<td>' +
                    '<a href="#"><i class="material-icons">edit</i></a>' +
                    '<a href="#" class="col-lg-1"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>' +
                    '</td>';
                output += '</tr>'
            }
            document.getElementById('articles').innerHTML = output;
        };
    };
    xhr.send();
}
function ArticleController() {
    this.indexAction = function() {
        this.getAllArticles();
    };
};

var articles = new ArticleController();
articles.indexAction();
```

Вот так выглядит табличка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какой таблицы? Минимальный код? Ожидаемый результат и текущий результат?

Comment: @NeedHate, обычная таблица на 5 колонок. Надо чтобы записи подгружались по 20 штук.

Comment: Покажите нам таблицу... больше информации - больше помощи.

Comment: @NeedHate, добавила код получения данных для таблицы и вид таблицы.

Comment: Если такое есть с jQuery - можно сделать и без jQuery. В крайнем случае взяв исходники jQuery и соответствующего плагина ленивой подгрузки (если такой есть - а наверняка должен быть). Но мастерить свой велосипед - зачастую долго, сложно, а качество результата может оставлять желать лучшего, особенно если велосипед начнет со временем усложняться.

Comment: А вы хотите по 20 штук загружать с использованием pagination, или по мере скролла страницы?

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, по мере скрола страницы)

Comment: А серверный скрипт, который выдаёт строки заданной страницы есть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно. Для этого нужно решить несколько задач.

1. Определение прокрутки страницы в самый низ;
2. Создание на сервере специального метода, который будет возвращать 
   дополнительные строки;
3. Выполнение с клиента асинхронного запроса на догрузку таблицы по событию из п.1;
4. Отрисовка полученных от сервера данных на странице.

**1. Определение прокрутки страницы в самый низ (когда нужно будет подгрузка)**

Для того что бы определить, что страница была промотана в самый низ, нужно взять разницу между двумя величинами: высота всей страницы в пикселях и смещение экрана (или viewport) относительно начала страницы + высота этого самого экрана. Чем меньше разница, тем ниже прокручена страница и тем скорее нужно начать загружать дополнительные строки.

**2. Создание на сервере специального метода, который будет возвращать дополнительные строки**

Серверный метод должен принимать от клиента информацию о том, сколько строк уже было загружено или с какой строки нужно начать. Обычно это делается так:

/feed.php?offset=20&limit=20

Что означает: верни мне 20 строк начиная с 20ой. Что сервер и должен сделать в виде JSON или уже в отрисованном виде. Зависит от реализации приложения.

**3. Выполнение с клиента асинхронного запроса на догрузку таблицы по событию из п.1**

У вас эта задача уже решена за исключением отправки сведений о требуемом клиентом количестве строк и смещении.

**4. Отрисовка полученных от сервера данных на странице**

У вас это так же реализовано.